# Gmail on Outlook 2010 with Exchange services?

Tags: gmail, sync, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have recently configure GMail on my iPhone with exchange services, which allows me to sync Mail, Contact and calendar. Is it possible to use Gmail in Outlook 2010 with exchange services?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

ActiveSync is different from what Outlook uses and Gmail doesn't provide Exchange for Outlook.

The closest that you can get is to use [IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725) to receive e-mail, and [KiGoo](http://www.getkigoo.com/) for Calendar and Contacts.

Comment: It _does_ provide Exchange servers for iPhone push - http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252

Comment: Exchange for Outlook differs from the Exchange Direct Push services...

Answer (score 2):

Google only offer this on their Google Apps for Business mail accounts ($50/year). You will need to install a plugin also.

http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/outlook_sync.html